# Implement Redis point-to-point queue to guarantee message processing once by any consumer

Tags: redis, middleware, spring-data-redis

Redis has very good implementation for PUBSUB where a message published on a channel will be received by multiple receivers registered for the topic.

What is the ideal way to implement point-to-point (i.e. queue) semantics where e.g. multiple receivers are registered with a single queue and as soon as a message is pushed to the queue it will be processed by only 1 receiver (listener)? Any Java reference example would help.

Here the idea is to a read huge file containing transaction records and hence each transaction should be processed only once.

I could see Redis Streams is advised, but I do not see a sound Java reference implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there is no direct implementation like for PUBSUB topic . Another reason to use Queue here is that there is no Durable Subscription in Publish Subscribve as well i.e. when subscriber is not up when the message sent your message will be lost. but below Queue implementation would save bit here.
**Final Answer**

LPUSH TEST_QUEUE Test message
LLEN TEST_QUEUE
BRPOP TEST_QUEUE 0

**Java Implementation**

```
while(true){
redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("TEST_QUEUE",0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
int keySize =this.pushOperation.size("TEST_QUEUE"); 
//iterate keySize {
redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("TEST_QUEUE",0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LPUSH msgqueue` to put items in the the list and have all clients do:

```
while running
    BRPOP msgqueue
    # process popped item
done
```

Comment: isn't there a ideal way like listener (like JMS queue) to get a callback to listener the way it is happening in PUBSUB e.g. SUBSCRIBE TEST_QUEUE  and then do             PUBLISH TEST_QUEUE MY_TEST_MESSAGE. Here it will be more of un necessary querying will be done on respective queue and which is kind of wasting resources is what I think. Why don't they have queue implementation straight away

Comment: Accepting this answer as there was no straight implementation I could find for redis. However below is the implementation work.                                           LPUSH TEST_QUEUE Test message
LLEN TEST_QUEUE
BRPOP TEST_QUEUE 0                                                                                            Java Implementation
while(true){
redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("TEST_QUEUE",0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
int keySize =this.pushOperation.size("TEST_QUEUE"); 
//iterate keySize {
redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("TEST_QUEUE",0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
}